# How to prevent from calling recursively error functions in Angular 5?

Tags: typescript, angular5

Do you know how to prevent the repetitive calls of functions when you have a recursive function ?

Here is the code :

```
loadFinalData(id, color){
    this.data = this._test.getUrl(id, "white");
    this.dataHover = this._test.getUrl(id, "blue");
}

private flux: Subscription;

loadData(id, color) {

    if(this.flux) this.flux.unsubscribe();

    this.flux = this._test.getData(id, "white")
    .subscribe( 
        res => this.loadFinalData(id, "white"),
        err => setTimeout( _ => this.loadData(id, "white"), 5000 )
    )
};
```

Here, we call the loadData function recursively.

The problem is that we have the err function of the subcribe() part that is calling every 5 seconds and it never stops (the unsubscribe() doesn't work).

Comment: Aren't you actually making a new subscription when the error is emitted?

Comment: Yes, i am doing this because i want to call again and again the loadData function until there is no error.

Comment: But shouldn't something happen before you request again? Either wait for something or change some type of param, this way you are recursively making requests

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work better for you. This will attempt 3 times and then stop:

```
public loadData(id, color) {
    this._test.getData(id, 'white')
        .retryWhen(retryObs$ => retryObs$
            .zip(Rx.Observable.range(1, 3), (_, i) => i)
            .delay(5000))
        .subscribe((res) => this.loadFinalData(id, 'white'));
}
```

You can play around with functionality surrounding this using the following snippet:

```
(function () {
    const attempts = 5;
    var obs = Rx.Observable.interval(10)
        .do((val) => { if (val > 2) throw val; })
        .do((val) => console.log(`Have value: ${val}`))
        .retryWhen(retryObs$ => retryObs$
            .zip(Rx.Observable.range(1, attempts), (_, i) => i)
            .do((attempt) => console.log(`Failed attempt #${attempt}`))
            .do((attempt) => {if (attempt === attempts) throw 'Thrown error'})
            .delay(100))
        .catch((err, obs$) => (console.log(`Received error: ${err}`), Rx.Observable.throw('Rethrown error')));
    var sub = obs.subscribe();
    setTimeout(() => sub.unsubscribe(), 5000);
})()
```

More information can be found in the RX book here: https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/creating_and_querying_observable_sequences/error_handling.html